Flowchart of ReduceLROnPlateau in keras during training while there is EarlyStopping callback
I have this fit statement:
 history = model.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train,
            validation_data=(X_val, y_val),
            batch_size=batch_size,
            epochs=epochs,
            verbose=1,
            callbacks=[early_stop,
                        reduce_lr,
                        checkpoint])

And here is the callbacks:
  checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(model_filepath,
                                monitor="val_loss",
                                verbose=1,
                                save_best_only=True,
                                mode='min',  # on acc has to go max
                                save_weights_only=True)

  reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor="val_loss",
                                factor=0.5,
                                min_delta=0.05,
                                mode='min',  # on acc has to go max
                                patience=2,
                                min_lr=minimum_lr,
                                verbose=1)

  early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss",  # "val_loss"
                              min_delta=0.05,
                              mode='min',  # on acc has to go max
                              patience=10,
                              verbose=1)

I just want to make sure if my flowchart is correct during training, and here is my FlowChart:


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="398px" viewBox="-0.5 -0.5 398 961" content="&lt;mxfile host=&quot;app.diagrams.net&quot; modified=&quot;2024-06-14T20:27:42.412Z&quot; agent=&quot;Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:127.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/127.0&quot; etag=&quot;zJQlWWc-WGR8iUCy7qNg&quot; version=&quot;24.5.3&quot; type=&quot;device&quot;&gt;&#xA;  &lt;diagram name=&quot;Page-1&quot; id=&quot;jGaBVrg6QGQQfozNtAgD&quot;&gt;&#xA;    &lt;mxGraphModel dx=&quot;1914&quot; dy=&quot;1011&quot; grid=&quot;1&quot; gridSize=&quot;10&quot; guides=&quot;1&quot; tooltips=&quot;1&quot; connect=&quot;1&quot; arrows=&quot;1&quot; fold=&quot;1&quot; page=&quot;1&quot; pageScale=&quot;1&quot; pageWidth=&quot;1100&quot; pageHeight=&quot;850&quot; math=&quot;0&quot; shadow=&quot;0&quot;&gt;&#xA;      &lt;root&gt;&#xA;        &lt;mxCell id=&quot;0&quot; /&gt;&#xA;        &lt;mxCell id=&quot;1&quot; parent=&quot;0&quot; /&gt;&#xA;        &lt;mxCell id=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-19&quot; style=&quot;edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;rounded=0;orthogonalLoop=1;jettySize=auto;html=1;exitX=0.5;exitY=1;exitDx=0;exitDy=0;entryX=0.5;entryY=0;entryDx=0;entryDy=0;&quot; edge=&quot;1&quot; parent=&quot;1&quot; source=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-1&quot; target=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-4&quot;&gt;&#xA;          &lt;mxGeometry relative=&quot;1&quot; as=&quot;geometry&quot; /&gt;&#xA;        &lt;/mxCell&gt;&#xA;        &lt;mxCell id=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-1&quot; value=&quot;Start Train&quot; style=&quot;ellipse;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;&quot; vertex=&quot;1&quot; parent=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&#xA;          &lt;mxGeometry x=&quot;440&quot; y=&quot;210&quot; width=&quot;120&quot; height=&quot;80&quot; as=&quot;geometry&quot; /&gt;&#xA;        &lt;/mxCell&gt;&#xA;        &lt;mxCell id=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-2&quot; value=&quot;Finish&quot; style=&quot;ellipse;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;&quot; vertex=&quot;1&quot; parent=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&#xA;          &lt;mxGeometry x=&quot;440&quot; y=&quot;1090&quot; width=&quot;120&quot; height=&quot;80&quot; as=&quot;geometry&quot; /&gt;&#xA;        &lt;/mxCell&gt;&#xA;        &lt;mxCell id=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-7&quot; style=&quot;edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;rounded=0;orthogonalLoop=1;jettySize=auto;html=1;exitX=0.5;exitY=1;exitDx=0;exitDy=0;entryX=0.5;entryY=0;entryDx=0;entryDy=0;&quot; edge=&quot;1&quot; parent=&quot;1&quot; source=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-3&quot; target=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-5&quot;&gt;&#xA;          &lt;mxGeometry relative=&quot;1&quot; as=&quot;geometry&quot; /&gt;&#xA;        &lt;/mxCell&gt;&#xA;        &lt;mxCell id=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-8&quot; value=&quot;True&quot; style=&quot;edgeLabel;html=1;align=center;verticalAlign=middle;resizable=0;points=[];&quot; vertex=&quot;1&quot; connectable=&quot;0&quot; parent=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-7&quot;&gt;&#xA;          &lt;mxGeometry x=&quot;-0.3238&quot; y=&quot;-1&quot; relative=&quot;1&quot; as=&quot;geometry&quot;&gt;&#xA;            &lt;mxPoint as=&quot;offset&quot; /&gt;&#xA;          &lt;/mxGeometry&gt;&#xA;        &lt;/mxCell&gt;&#xA;        &lt;mxCell id=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-11&quot; style=&quot;edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;rounded=0;orthogonalLoop=1;jettySize=auto;html=1;exitX=0;exitY=0.5;exitDx=0;exitDy=0;entryX=0;entryY=0.5;entryDx=0;entryDy=0;&quot; edge=&quot;1&quot; parent=&quot;1&quot; source=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-3&quot; target=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-4&quot;&gt;&#xA;          &lt;mxGeometry relative=&quot;1&quot; as=&quot;geometry&quot;&gt;&#xA;            &lt;Array as=&quot;points&quot;&gt;&#xA;              &lt;mxPoint x=&quot;380&quot; y=&quot;520&quot; /&gt;&#xA;              &lt;mxPoint x=&quot;380&quot; y=&quot;350&quot; /&gt;&#xA;            &lt;/Array&gt;&#xA;          &lt;/mxGeometry&gt;&#xA;        &lt;/mxCell&gt;&#xA;        &lt;mxCell id=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-3&quot; value=&quot;Is val_loss not improved?&quot; style=&quot;rhombus;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;&quot; vertex=&quot;1&quot; parent=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&#xA;          &lt;mxGeometry x=&quot;420&quot; y=&quot;440&quot; width=&quot;160&quot; height=&quot;160&quot; as=&quot;geometry&quot; /&gt;&#xA;        &lt;/mxCell&gt;&#xA;        &lt;mxCell id=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-6&quot; style=&quot;edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;rounded=0;orthogonalLoop=1;jettySize=auto;html=1;exitX=0.5;exitY=1;exitDx=0;exitDy=0;entryX=0.5;entryY=0;entryDx=0;entryDy=0;&quot; edge=&quot;1&quot; parent=&quot;1&quot; source=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-4&quot; target=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-3&quot;&gt;&#xA;          &lt;mxGeometry relative=&quot;1&quot; as=&quot;geometry&quot; /&gt;&#xA;        &lt;/mxCell&gt;&#xA;        &lt;mxCell id=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-4&quot; value=&quot;Train 1 Epoch&quot; style=&quot;rounded=0;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;&quot; vertex=&quot;1&quot; parent=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&#xA;          &lt;mxGeometry x=&quot;440&quot; y=&quot;320&quot; width=&quot;120&quot; height=&quot;60&quot; as=&quot;geometry&quot; /&gt;&#xA;        &lt;/mxCell&gt;&#xA;        &lt;mxCell id=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-24&quot; style=&quot;edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;rounded=0;orthogonalLoop=1;jettySize=auto;html=1;exitX=0.5;exitY=1;exitDx=0;exitDy=0;entryX=0.5;entryY=0;entryDx=0;entryDy=0;&quot; edge=&quot;1&quot; parent=&quot;1&quot; source=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-5&quot; target=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-21&quot;&gt;&#xA;          &lt;mxGeometry relative=&quot;1&quot; as=&quot;geometry&quot; /&gt;&#xA;        &lt;/mxCell&gt;&#xA;        &lt;mxCell id=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-27&quot; style=&quot;edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;rounded=0;orthogonalLoop=1;jettySize=auto;html=1;exitX=1;exitY=0.5;exitDx=0;exitDy=0;entryX=0;entryY=0.5;entryDx=0;entryDy=0;&quot; edge=&quot;1&quot; parent=&quot;1&quot; source=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-5&quot; target=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-17&quot;&gt;&#xA;          &lt;mxGeometry relative=&quot;1&quot; as=&quot;geometry&quot; /&gt;&#xA;        &lt;/mxCell&gt;&#xA;        &lt;mxCell id=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-5&quot; value=&quot;2 times?&quot; style=&quot;rhombus;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;&quot; vertex=&quot;1&quot; parent=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&#xA;          &lt;mxGeometry x=&quot;420&quot; y=&quot;660&quot; width=&quot;160&quot; height=&quot;160&quot; as=&quot;geometry&quot; /&gt;&#xA;        &lt;/mxCell&gt;&#xA;        &lt;mxCell id=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-9&quot; value=&quot;False&quot; style=&quot;edgeLabel;html=1;align=center;verticalAlign=middle;resizable=0;points=[];&quot; vertex=&quot;1&quot; connectable=&quot;0&quot; parent=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&#xA;          &lt;mxGeometry x=&quot;410&quot; y=&quot;500.0014285714287&quot; as=&quot;geometry&quot;&gt;&#xA;            &lt;mxPoint x=&quot;2&quot; y=&quot;3&quot; as=&quot;offset&quot; /&gt;&#xA;          &lt;/mxGeometry&gt;&#xA;        &lt;/mxCell&gt;&#xA;        &lt;mxCell id=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-14&quot; value=&quot;False&quot; style=&quot;edgeLabel;html=1;align=center;verticalAlign=middle;resizable=0;points=[];&quot; vertex=&quot;1&quot; connectable=&quot;0&quot; parent=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&#xA;          &lt;mxGeometry x=&quot;530&quot; y=&quot;650.0014285714287&quot; as=&quot;geometry&quot;&gt;&#xA;            &lt;mxPoint x=&quot;-11&quot; y=&quot;189&quot; as=&quot;offset&quot; /&gt;&#xA;          &lt;/mxGeometry&gt;&#xA;        &lt;/mxCell&gt;&#xA;        &lt;mxCell id=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-29&quot; style=&quot;edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;rounded=0;orthogonalLoop=1;jettySize=auto;html=1;exitX=0.5;exitY=0;exitDx=0;exitDy=0;entryX=1;entryY=0.5;entryDx=0;entryDy=0;&quot; edge=&quot;1&quot; parent=&quot;1&quot; source=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-17&quot; target=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-4&quot;&gt;&#xA;          &lt;mxGeometry relative=&quot;1&quot; as=&quot;geometry&quot; /&gt;&#xA;        &lt;/mxCell&gt;&#xA;        &lt;mxCell id=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-17&quot; value=&quot;Reduce current learning rate by factor 0.5&quot; style=&quot;rounded=0;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;&quot; vertex=&quot;1&quot; parent=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&#xA;          &lt;mxGeometry x=&quot;650&quot; y=&quot;710&quot; width=&quot;120&quot; height=&quot;60&quot; as=&quot;geometry&quot; /&gt;&#xA;        &lt;/mxCell&gt;&#xA;        &lt;mxCell id=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-25&quot; style=&quot;edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;rounded=0;orthogonalLoop=1;jettySize=auto;html=1;exitX=0;exitY=0.5;exitDx=0;exitDy=0;&quot; edge=&quot;1&quot; parent=&quot;1&quot; source=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-21&quot;&gt;&#xA;          &lt;mxGeometry relative=&quot;1&quot; as=&quot;geometry&quot;&gt;&#xA;            &lt;mxPoint x=&quot;380&quot; y=&quot;520&quot; as=&quot;targetPoint&quot; /&gt;&#xA;          &lt;/mxGeometry&gt;&#xA;        &lt;/mxCell&gt;&#xA;        &lt;mxCell id=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-31&quot; style=&quot;edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;rounded=0;orthogonalLoop=1;jettySize=auto;html=1;exitX=0.5;exitY=1;exitDx=0;exitDy=0;&quot; edge=&quot;1&quot; parent=&quot;1&quot; source=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-21&quot;&gt;&#xA;          &lt;mxGeometry relative=&quot;1&quot; as=&quot;geometry&quot;&gt;&#xA;            &lt;mxPoint x=&quot;500&quot; y=&quot;1090.0000000000002&quot; as=&quot;targetPoint&quot; /&gt;&#xA;          &lt;/mxGeometry&gt;&#xA;        &lt;/mxCell&gt;&#xA;        &lt;mxCell id=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-21&quot; value=&quot;10 times?&quot; style=&quot;rhombus;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;&quot; vertex=&quot;1&quot; parent=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&#xA;          &lt;mxGeometry x=&quot;420&quot; y=&quot;880&quot; width=&quot;160&quot; height=&quot;160&quot; as=&quot;geometry&quot; /&gt;&#xA;        &lt;/mxCell&gt;&#xA;        &lt;mxCell id=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-26&quot; value=&quot;False&quot; style=&quot;edgeLabel;html=1;align=center;verticalAlign=middle;resizable=0;points=[];&quot; vertex=&quot;1&quot; connectable=&quot;0&quot; parent=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&#xA;          &lt;mxGeometry x=&quot;410&quot; y=&quot;760.0014285714287&quot; as=&quot;geometry&quot;&gt;&#xA;            &lt;mxPoint x=&quot;-11&quot; y=&quot;189&quot; as=&quot;offset&quot; /&gt;&#xA;          &lt;/mxGeometry&gt;&#xA;        &lt;/mxCell&gt;&#xA;        &lt;mxCell id=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-28&quot; value=&quot;True&quot; style=&quot;edgeLabel;html=1;align=center;verticalAlign=middle;resizable=0;points=[];&quot; vertex=&quot;1&quot; connectable=&quot;0&quot; parent=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&#xA;          &lt;mxGeometry x=&quot;509.00000000000045&quot; y=&quot;660&quot; as=&quot;geometry&quot;&gt;&#xA;            &lt;mxPoint x=&quot;102&quot; y=&quot;57&quot; as=&quot;offset&quot; /&gt;&#xA;          &lt;/mxGeometry&gt;&#xA;        &lt;/mxCell&gt;&#xA;        &lt;mxCell id=&quot;refrSsMn6WbcP44MQN3y-30&quot; value=&quot;True&quot; style=&quot;edgeLabel;html=1;align=center;verticalAlign=middle;resizable=0;points=[];&quot; vertex=&quot;1&quot; connectable=&quot;0&quot; parent=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&#xA;          &lt;mxGeometry x=&quot;530&quot; y=&quot;860.0014285714287&quot; as=&quot;geometry&quot;&gt;&#xA;            &lt;mxPoint x=&quot;-11&quot; y=&quot;189&quot; as=&quot;offset&quot; /&gt;&#xA;          &lt;/mxGeometry&gt;&#xA;        &lt;/mxCell&gt;&#xA;      &lt;/root&gt;&#xA;    &lt;/mxGraphModel&gt;&#xA;  &lt;/diagram&gt;&#xA;&lt;/mxfile&gt;&#xA;" onclick="(function(svg){var src=window.event.target||window.event.srcElement;while (src!=null&amp;&amp;src.nodeName.toLowerCase()!='a'){src=src.parentNode;}if(src==null){if(svg.wnd!=null&amp;&amp;!svg.wnd.closed){svg.wnd.focus();}else{var r=function(evt){if(evt.data=='ready'&amp;&amp;evt.source==svg.wnd){svg.wnd.postMessage(decodeURIComponent(svg.getAttribute('content')),'*');window.removeEventListener('message',r);}};window.addEventListener('message',r);svg.wnd=window.open('https://viewer.diagrams.net/?client=1&amp;page=0&amp;edit=_blank');}}})(this);" style="cursor:pointer;max-width:100%;max-height:961px;"><defs/><g><g><path d="M 127 80 L 127 103.63" fill="none" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke"/><path d="M 127 108.88 L 123.5 101.88 L 127 103.63 L 130.5 101.88 Z" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"/></g><g><ellipse cx="127" cy="40" rx="60" ry="40" fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" pointer-events="all"/></g><g><g transform="translate(-0.5 -0.5)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 118px; height: 1px; padding-top: 40px; margin-left: 68px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0px; text-align: center;" data-drawio-colors="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; overflow-wrap: normal;">Start Train</div></div></div></foreignObject><text x="127" y="44" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="12px" text-anchor="middle">Start Train</text></switch></g></g><g><ellipse cx="127" cy="920" rx="60" ry="40" fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" pointer-events="all"/></g><g><g transform="translate(-0.5 -0.5)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 118px; height: 1px; padding-top: 920px; margin-left: 68px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0px; text-align: center;" data-drawio-colors="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; overflow-wrap: normal;">Finish</div></div></div></foreignObject><text x="127" y="924" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="12px" text-anchor="middle">Finish</text></switch></g></g><g><path d="M 127 390 L 127 443.63" fill="none" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke"/><path d="M 127 448.88 L 123.5 441.88 L 127 443.63 L 130.5 441.88 Z" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"/></g><g><g transform="translate(-0.5 -0.5)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 1px; height: 1px; padding-top: 411px; margin-left: 127px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0px; text-align: center;" data-drawio-colors="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 11px; font-family: Helvetica; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); white-space: nowrap;">True</div></div></div></foreignObject><text x="127" y="414" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="11px" text-anchor="middle">True</text></switch></g></g><g><path d="M 47 310 L 7 310 L 7 140 L 60.63 140" fill="none" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke"/><path d="M 65.88 140 L 58.88 143.5 L 60.63 140 L 58.88 136.5 Z" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"/></g><g><path d="M 127 230 L 207 310 L 127 390 L 47 310 Z" fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"/></g><g><g transform="translate(-0.5 -0.5)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 158px; height: 1px; padding-top: 310px; margin-left: 48px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0px; text-align: center;" data-drawio-colors="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; overflow-wrap: normal;">Is val_loss not improved?</div></div></div></foreignObject><text x="127" y="314" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="12px" text-anchor="middle">Is val_loss not improved?</text></switch></g></g><g><path d="M 127 170 L 127 223.63" fill="none" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke"/><path d="M 127 228.88 L 123.5 221.88 L 127 223.63 L 130.5 221.88 Z" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"/></g><g><rect x="67" y="110" width="120" height="60" fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" pointer-events="all"/></g><g><g transform="translate(-0.5 -0.5)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 118px; height: 1px; padding-top: 140px; margin-left: 68px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0px; text-align: center;" data-drawio-colors="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; overflow-wrap: normal;">Train 1 Epoch</div></div></div></foreignObject><text x="127" y="144" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="12px" text-anchor="middle">Train 1 Epoch</text></switch></g></g><g><path d="M 127 610 L 127 663.63" fill="none" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke"/><path d="M 127 668.88 L 123.5 661.88 L 127 663.63 L 130.5 661.88 Z" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"/></g><g><path d="M 207 530 L 270.63 530" fill="none" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke"/><path d="M 275.88 530 L 268.88 533.5 L 270.63 530 L 268.88 526.5 Z" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"/></g><g><path d="M 127 450 L 207 530 L 127 610 L 47 530 Z" fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"/></g><g><g transform="translate(-0.5 -0.5)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 158px; height: 1px; padding-top: 530px; margin-left: 48px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0px; text-align: center;" data-drawio-colors="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; overflow-wrap: normal;">2 times?</div></div></div></foreignObject><text x="127" y="534" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="12px" text-anchor="middle">2 times?</text></switch></g></g><g><g transform="translate(-0.5 -0.5)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 1px; height: 1px; padding-top: 294px; margin-left: 40px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0px; text-align: center;" data-drawio-colors="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 11px; font-family: Helvetica; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); white-space: nowrap;">False</div></div></div></foreignObject><text x="40" y="297" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="11px" text-anchor="middle">False</text></switch></g></g><g><g transform="translate(-0.5 -0.5)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 1px; height: 1px; padding-top: 630px; margin-left: 147px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0px; text-align: center;" data-drawio-colors="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 11px; font-family: Helvetica; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); white-space: nowrap;">False</div></div></div></foreignObject><text x="147" y="633" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="11px" text-anchor="middle">False</text></switch></g></g><g><path d="M 337 500 L 337 140 L 193.37 140" fill="none" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke"/><path d="M 188.12 140 L 195.12 136.5 L 193.37 140 L 195.12 143.5 Z" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"/></g><g><rect x="277" y="500" width="120" height="60" fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" pointer-events="all"/></g><g><g transform="translate(-0.5 -0.5)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 118px; height: 1px; padding-top: 530px; margin-left: 278px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0px; text-align: center;" data-drawio-colors="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; overflow-wrap: normal;">Reduce current learning rate by factor 0.5</div></div></div></foreignObject><text x="337" y="534" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="12px" text-anchor="middle">Reduce current learn...</text></switch></g></g><g><path d="M 47 750 L 7.5 750 L 7.01 316.37" fill="none" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke"/><path d="M 7 311.12 L 10.51 318.11 L 7.01 316.37 L 3.51 318.12 Z" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"/></g><g><path d="M 127 830 L 127 855 L 127 873.63" fill="none" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke"/><path d="M 127 878.88 L 123.5 871.88 L 127 873.63 L 130.5 871.88 Z" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"/></g><g><path d="M 127 670 L 207 750 L 127 830 L 47 750 Z" fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"/></g><g><g transform="translate(-0.5 -0.5)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 158px; height: 1px; padding-top: 750px; margin-left: 48px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0px; text-align: center;" data-drawio-colors="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; overflow-wrap: normal;">10 times?</div></div></div></foreignObject><text x="127" y="754" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="12px" text-anchor="middle">10 times?</text></switch></g></g><g><g transform="translate(-0.5 -0.5)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 1px; height: 1px; padding-top: 740px; margin-left: 27px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0px; text-align: center;" data-drawio-colors="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 11px; font-family: Helvetica; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); white-space: nowrap;">False</div></div></div></foreignObject><text x="27" y="743" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="11px" text-anchor="middle">False</text></switch></g></g><g><g transform="translate(-0.5 -0.5)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 1px; height: 1px; padding-top: 508px; margin-left: 239px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0px; text-align: center;" data-drawio-colors="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 11px; font-family: Helvetica; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); white-space: nowrap;">True</div></div></div></foreignObject><text x="239" y="511" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="11px" text-anchor="middle">True</text></switch></g></g><g><g transform="translate(-0.5 -0.5)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 1px; height: 1px; padding-top: 840px; margin-left: 147px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0px; text-align: center;" data-drawio-colors="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 11px; font-family: Helvetica; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); white-space: nowrap;">True</div></div></div></foreignObject><text x="147" y="843" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="11px" text-anchor="middle">True</text></switch></g></g></g><switch><g requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"/><a transform="translate(0,-5)" xlink:href="https://www.drawio.com/doc/faq/svg-export-text-problems" target="_blank"><text text-anchor="middle" font-size="10px" x="50%" y="100%">Text is not SVG - cannot display</text></a></switch></svg>



